# Celery retry task locally?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, celery

Currently I have a group of tasks running in parallel, when an error occurs celery sends the retried task back to queue and moves on with the next task in queue, but the problem the next task will also face the same error and will cause a retry. I only fix the problem at the 3rd retry because most times just retrying the task will get the job done, so every task in the queue goes through this retry phase needlessly 3 times, before the problem can be fixed, this can be avoided if I can force celery to execute the retry tasks locally. So there anyway to tell celery to retry the tasks locally?

Answer (score 0):

One (me included) could argue that if you want to re-try locally you should simply handle the exception(s) in your task by yourself, especially considering that you want to preserve some states between retries.

As far as I know Celery will not do it for you. If I am not mistaken you could file a feature request and hope they do it in foreseeable future.